# GAE one to many Relationship JDO Example

Tags: java, class, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo

I read GAE doc about JDO but i didn't find such example that fit to my scenario. Please help me.

I have two JDO classes like `A` and `B`. `"A"` class have one to many relationship with `"B"`. This relation is unowed also not dependent. class `"A"` and `"B"` has following structure (to make it simple i am not using annotations)

```
class A {

private String name;
private String id; // primary Key
private List<B> b;

..... getter setter
}

class B {

private Key key; // primary Key
private String id; // this is the attribute of the Class A
private String someData;

}
```

Now my scenario is that First I created class `"A"` objects one by one and save it to the data store using Persistent manager. For this storing "`List<B> b` " will be null bcz i don't have data for it.

After that lets suppose I provide a form that have two fields one for the `"id"` attribute of the Class "`A"` and other for "`someData`" attibute. In this user provide the `"id"` of one of the stored objects of class `"A"`. When User submit the result i have to create a class `"B"` object and save it to data store and also have to add it in `list of B` of its corresponding Class `"A"` object. I hope you understand what i want to do.

Now my question is that what approach i have to use for maintaining this one to many relationship of JDO classes. Either i have to first retrieve the class `"A"` object based on the `"id"` provided in the form and after getting the object i get `"list of B"` class objects and add a `"B"` class object in the list and then save the class `"A"` object( As object is attached to the PM its automatically save) or other approach is that I just create the class `"B"` object and save it to the data store using PM.

If just creating `B` class object and saving it to the data store is persistent to the relationship. I simple word when i get the class `A` objects does `"list of B"` class object have the all objects linked to class "A" object ( because B class has attribute which is the primary key of class `A` )

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the GAE/J documentation at [Java | Storing Data | Datastore | JDO | Entity Relationships in JDO | Unowned Relationships](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Unowned_Relationships) should help you here.

Because the relationship between `A` and `B` is unowned, all `A` and `B` instances are in separate entity groups. Therefore, you will have to perform two separate persistence operations to create/update/delete an instance of `B` and update the relevant instance of `A` accordingly.

Does this help?